# Will synthetic data (e.g. from a generative model) produce valid statistical inference?

Tags: inference, generative-models

Especially with chatGPT now, there is a lot of interest in generative models for healthcare for creating synthetic patient data to amplify patient counts, e.g. for rare diseases. These are then supposed to be used for purposes of statistical inference, e.g. to compare patient outcomes, estimate risk ratios etc.

My question is whether synthetic data can, in theory and practice, produce valid statistical inference, e.g. confidence intervals.

Edit: Adding some more detail, assume we have some measured data $X$. We are interested in estimating some statistics (mean, variance) based on this sample of data. Assume the data $X$ has $n$ observations, and we have a very flexible way of learning the joint distribution of the data using some state-of-the-art methods (e.g., GANs, sample sitting) which we can then use to simulate some artificial data $\hat{X}$. If we augment actual data with this simulated data, can we still validly estimate statistical quantities like means and variances for any/every possible scientific question/target of inference?

Comment: At least philosophically, how different is it to generate data to add to the sample in a frequentist approach and to use a prior distribution in a Bayesian approach?

Comment: *"These are then supposed to be used for purposes of statistical inference, e.g. to compare patient outcomes, estimate risk ratios etc."* I do not understand this use. The important part that is left away is *how* synthetic data is used for statistical inference. Is the synthetic data used like Monte Carlo stimulations, which seems fine to me (although there might be technical issues) or is the synthetic data used to replace real data, which I would not understand how that works.

Answer (score 9):

If you run a statistical analysis on synthetic data, you will get out what you put in.  That is, the results of the analysis will reflect the assumptions that went into your generative model.  This can be very useful for testing an analysis method; for example, you could test the sensitivity of the method to model misspecification.  However, you will not learn anything about the real world because there is nothing of the real world in your data.  In science there is no substitute for actually going out and gathering observations.

By the way, there is no need to use an AI program like GPT to generate synthetic data, nor is there any particular advantage in doing so.  People have been doing it for years (e.g., SynPUF).  For most purposes, using an opaque model like an LLM is actually a disadvantage because you don't know what assumptions are built into it, nor what the "correct" answer is for a model run on the simulated data.  In simulation studies you want to be able to compare your model's results to the theoretical values that you know based on how you set up the simulation.

Answer (score 5):

Must it produce a valid inference? **No!**

In the simulation below, I generate a sample of size $10$ that serves as the data. Then I generate synthetic data, based on the mean and variance from the sample. I combine the data and the synthetic data and calculate a confidence interval for the combination. I also calculate a confidence interval for the original data.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 10    # Sample size
S <- 1000  # Sample size wen synthetic data are added, so S - N synthetic points
R <- 10000 # Number of replications of the simulation
mu <- 0    # Population mean that will be estimated

level <- 0.95  # Confidence level

contained <- rep(1, R) # Does the forthcoming confidence interval contain mu?
                       # 1 for yes, 0 for no
contained_regular <- rep(1, R)

for (i in 1:R){
  
  # Simulate N-many points from N(mu, 1) to serve as original data
  # 
  x <- rnorm(N, mu, 1)
  
  # Simulate synthetic points from an assumed Gausian distribution that has
  # the empirical mean and standard deviation
  # 
  y <- rnorm(S - N, mean(x), sd(x))
  
  # Combine the synthetic and original data
  #
  d <- c(x, y)
  
  # Calculate a confidence interval for the mean
  #
  ci <- t.test(d, mu = mu, conf.level = level)$conf.int
  
  # Check if mu is below the lower or above the upper limit of the interval
  #
  if (ci[1] > mu){
    contained[i] <- 0
  }
  if (ci[2] < mu){
    contained[i] <- 0
  }
  
  # Check if the regular confidence interval (without the synthetic data)
  # contains mu
  #
  ci_regular <- t.test(x, mu = mu, conf.level = level)$conf.int
  if (ci_regular[1] > mu){
    contained_regular[i] <- 0
  }
  if (ci_regular[2] < mu){
    contained_regular[i] <- 0
  }
  
}

# Calculate the coverage of the confidence intervals: how many times they
# contain the true mu
#
mean(contained)
mean(contained_regular)
```

The confidence intervals from the real data contain the true parameter value in about the desired $95\%$ of cases ($95.11\%$). However, augmenting the data with synthetic data leads to the confidence intervals containing the true value in only $13.94\%$ of cases. That is, you think you’re calculating a $95\%$ confidence interval but actually get a $13.93\%$ confidence interval. Ouch!

What’s happening is that the synthetic data are generated to be similar to the data, not the data-generating process. Each time data are generated, they are generated using the estimated mean and variance, which are not the true mean and variance. This drags the synthetic data away from the true population of interest, distorting the statistical inference.

I hope this demonstrates potential dangers of using synthetic data. Philosophically, I do not see much of a difference between using synthetic data in frequentist methods and using an informative prior in Bayesian methods, and Bayesian methods can be very powerful, but if you pick a bad prior (or a bad way of generating synthetic data), you can wind up in trouble.

**EDIT**

Amazingly, the story doesn’t even get much better for `N <- 10000` and `S <- 100000`. I would have though that the estimated mean and variance would be so close to their true values with a sample size of `10000`, but they appear not to be close enough to give confidence intervals that function as they should.